# How to decrpt php yii encrpted password using java

Tags: java, php, yii

In yii2 using generatePasswordHash and validatePassword to verify password like this.
After encrypted it store in DB with password_hash

```
$2y$13$1hVeVwvuKQUE.kJfaQLje.b8iLlTauTOksddD5Gqn6UC416NsnAR2

auth_key oEx6MM0pGs6jHvApr2anxJEINpTpqGUO
```

Now how to using java to verify the password?
And what is the auth_key means, as verify don't need to input the auth_key.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142745/how-do-i-generate-a-salt-in-java-for-salted-hash

Answer (score 1):

All you need is create your custom Class in Java taking and converting from PHP class `\yii\base\Security` ([source is here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Security.php)). Regarding auth key this question already asked [here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167265/yii2-why-is-the-auth-key-in-class-user)

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved with the following, the tricky part is replace the header.

public class CheckPassword {

```
public static boolean checkPassword(String passwordText, String DbHash) {
    boolean password_verified = false;
    if (null != DbHash) {
        if (DbHash.startsWith("$2y$")) {
            DbHash = "$2a$" + DbHash.substring(4);
        }
    }

    if (null == DbHash || !DbHash.startsWith("$2a$")) {
        throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException("Invalid hash provided for comparison");
    }
    password_verified = BCrypt.checkpw(passwordText, DbHash);
    return (password_verified);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CheckPassword.checkPassword("xxxxx", "$2y$13$5mqgv2wZve89Bz.g1MUcg.7xNich7/nxxxxxxxxxx");

    try {
        String salt = getSalt();
        System.out.println("salt:" + salt);//获取salt
        String miwen = getPBKDF2("111", salt); //明文密码加密
        System.out.println("miwen:" + miwen);
        System.out.println(salt + miwen);
        System.out.println(verify("111", salt + miwen));//解密


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static final String PBKDF2_ALGORITHM = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";

//盐的长度
public static final int SALT_SIZE = 16;

//生成密文的长度
public static final int HASH_SIZE = 16;

// 迭代次数
public static final int PBKDF2_ITERATIONS = 1000;

/**
 * 对输入的密码进行验证
 * password 密码明文
 * dataPassWord 密码加密
 */
public static boolean verify(String password, String dataPassWord)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    // 用相同的盐值对用户输入的密码进行加密
    String result = getPBKDF2(password, dataPassWord.substring(0, 16));
    // 把加密后的密文和原密文进行比较，相同则验证成功，否则失败
    return result.equals(dataPassWord.substring(16, dataPassWord.length()));
}

/**
 * 根据password和salt生成密文
 */
public static String getPBKDF2(String password, String salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        InvalidKeySpecException {
    //将16进制字符串形式的salt转换成byte数组
    byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(salt);
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), bytes, PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, HASH_SIZE * 4);
    SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(PBKDF2_ALGORITHM);
    byte[] hash = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
    //将byte数组转换为16进制的字符串
    return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hash);
}


/**
 * 生成随机盐值
 */
public static String getSalt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    byte[] bytes = new byte[SALT_SIZE / 2];
    random.nextBytes(bytes);
    //将byte数组转换为16进制的字符串
    String salt = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(bytes);
    return salt;
}
```

}